# Google sheets : suppress warning onEdit

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

For a Google Sheet, I copied & pasted bits and pieces of scripts I found online to have a warning message show whenever someone edited something in column F. This is working as intended (but maybe a bit slow to 'react').

However, once a month, every value in column F needs to be manually updated by default so in that case, I'd like to have the option to let the users of this sheet skip the warning message or supress the message from being shown.

Is something like that possible? You can find the code below.

```
function onEdit(e) {//"e" receives the event object
  var range = e.range;//The range of cells edited

  var columnOfCellEdited = range.getColumn();//Get column number
  //Logger.log(columnOfCellEdited)

  if (columnOfCellEdited === 6) {
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('You edited the budget column for an account. Sure you dont need to change the account budget in the account?.');
     };
};
```

Comment: Welcome. Off the top of my head... how about a checkbox for the once-a-month task? User ticks the box, and onEdit is modified so that if checkbox is NOT ticked, the alert is shown, and if ticked, the alert is NOT shown.

Comment: Hi.
Thanks for your reply! Do you mean a checkbox in the warning message so it no longer shows again after the first warning? or a checkbox somewhere in the sheet so the warning nver triggers?
The thing is that the warning is valid for the once-a-month task, but it's pointless(or annoying) to show it when a user is updating each row. Having the warning show once would be preferred, but if that's not possible, then a checkbox somewhere in the sheet would be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using a checkbox to enable monthly update.**

You have some onEdit code that warns users that they are making changes to the budget figures in Column F. However once a month there must be extensive editing of the figures in this column, and the the onEdit warning must be turned off.

Say you have a checkbox in cell E1 (with an appropriate label). If you tick the checkbox, it will turn the warning off. If the box is not ticked, then the warning message will be displayed.

The following code would be one way of doing this. The key is the "IF" statement:

`if (columnOfCellEdited === 6 && monthlyChk === false) {`

This will display the warning only if the edit is in Column F AND if the checkbox is not ticked. You may be concerned about leaving the checkbox in open sight, but you can put/hide the checkbox anywhere you want on the spreadsheet so long as it is appropriately referenced in the code.

---

[image]

---

```
function onEdit(e){
  //so5920976001
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = e.range;//The range of cells edited
  var sheet = range.getSheet();


  var columnOfCellEdited = range.getColumn();//Get column number

  // checkbox in Cell E1 indicates whether to override for monthly manual adjustments
  var monthlyChk = sheet.getRange("E1").getValue();



  if (columnOfCellEdited === 6 && monthlyChk === false) {
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('You edited the budget column for an account. Sure you dont need to change the account budget in the account?.');
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try implementing this.